# too many audio tags make my website load very slowly. is there a solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a website (not on air yet) and I tested it live with some free hosting.
The website contains a map tag and a big picture within it.
I made it so if someone clicks on a part of the picture a specific audio will be heard, according to where he clicked.

My problem is that there are a lot of audio tags (about 300) and because there are lots of bandwidth-hogging files, it takes about 10 minutes until the website is fully loaded which means most of the audios don't work for several minutes.

I want to know if there is a way, maybe a responsive way with javascript or PHP that will allow me to make those audio tags only if the user clicks on the map. That way it will not use that much bandwidth. Also if anyone can think of a better way it will greatly appreciated.

I'm adding the javascript for the click event so you can see what it is all about -

```
$('#Swensens_maze').click(function(){
        $('audio').each(function(){
        this.pause(); // Stop playing
         // Reset time
        });
        $('#Swensens_maze_audio').get(0).play();
        return false;
    });
```

This is one example from many. The "#swensens_maze" is the area tag and the "#Swensens_maze_audio" is the audio tag for it.

Comment: Only load the audio files when needed via JS. This may cause some delay, but it's a more proper solution than loading all audio files at once.

Comment: Maybe you can store the original url inside an attribute called `data-original`, then when an user click on tag audio you can trough JQuery set the `src` attribute equal to `data-original`, basically a lazyload

Comment: A short answer would be to have a single `audio` element on the page and work out some `Javascript` to change its `src` attribute according to the clicked part on the image.

Comment: 1) what is the file format of your audio files ? 2) Could you use webAudio ? 3) what about using a single audio file and play different parts of it (audio sprite, using webAudio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** 
The audio now automatically strats
**EDIT 2** 
I have just remembered that an empty `src` is a bad practice, I will find a solution, the best one is to store the information in some other tag and then create a the audio tag with js
**EDIT 3**
[JS FIDDLE VERSION 2](http://jsfiddle.net/d7gwmu2f/3/)
Better version,doesn't leave an empty `src` attribute, all the audio information are stored inside the the hidden `input`, once you click the area the `audio` tag is provided through JS inside the clicked `div`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jq.js"></script>
        <style>
            .map {width:100%;height:75px;background:#bbb}
            .c1 {background:#f2f2f2}
            .c2 {background:#000}
            .c3 {background:#cc4444}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='map c1'>
            <input type='hidden' data-original='1.mp3' data-format="audio/mpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class='map c2'>
            <input type='hidden' data-original='2.mp3' data-format="audio/mpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class='map c3'>
            <input type='hidden' data-original='3.mp3' data-format="audio/mpeg" />
        </div>
        <script>
            $('div.map').click(function () {
                $('audio').each(function () {
                    this.pause();
                });
                //Check if audio is already present, if true, then exit
                if($(this).find('audio').length > 0)
                    return;

                var childInput  = $(this).find('input:hidden'), //Find information
                    audioTag    = document.createElement("AUDIO"),// Create AUDIO element
                    audioSource = document.createElement("SOURCE"), //Create SOURCE element
                    audioType   = childInput.attr('data-format'),//retrieve audio type, then you could checkif the browser supports this format
                    audioSrc    = childInput.attr('data-original'); //retrieve audio src

                //Set type and src of the source
                audioSource.type= audioType;
                audioSource.src= audioSrc;

                //Enable controls and append SOURCE to AUDIO
                audioTag.controls = true;
                audioTag.appendChild(audioSource);

                this.appendChild(audioTag);// Append the created audio tag to the clicked div
                audioTag.load();//Load the src

                audioTag.play();//Play the audio

                return false;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**OLDER ANSWER**
Bad for empty src
    $('div.map').click(function () {
                $('audio').each(function () {
                    this.pause();
                });
                var audioTag = $(this).find('audio'),
                    sourceTag=audioTag.children('source');

```
            if (sourceTag.attr('src')=='') {
                sourceTag.attr('src', sourceTag.attr('data-original'));
                audioTag.load()
            }

            audioTag.get(0).play();
            return false;
        });
```

Full page [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d7gwmu2f/1/)(the player doesn't appear, because there isn't any audio file):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jq.js"></script>
        <style>
            .map {
                width:100%;
                height:75px;
                background:#bbb
            }
            .c1 {
                background:#f2f2f2
            }
            .c2 {
                background:#000
            }
            .c3 {
                background:#cc4444
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='map c1'>
            <audio controls>
                <source data-original='1.mp3' src='' type="audio/mpeg" />
            </audio>
        </div>
        <div class='map c2'>
            <audio controls>
                <source data-original='2.mp3' src='' type="audio/mpeg" />
            </audio>
        </div>
        <div class='map c3'>
            <audio controls>
                <source data-original='3.mp3' src='' type="audio/mpeg" />
            </audio>
        </div>
        <script>
            $('div.map').click(function () {
                $('audio').each(function () {
                    this.pause();
                });
                var audioTag = $(this).find('audio'),
                    sourceTag=audioTag.children('source');

                if (sourceTag.attr('src')=='') {
                    sourceTag.attr('src', sourceTag.attr('data-original'));
                    audioTag.load()
                }

                audioTag.play();
                return false;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is the area - <area shape="rect" coords="2780,2276,2923,2365" href="" alt="falador_party_room" id="falador_party_room"> and this is the audio - <audio id="falador_party_room_audio">
<source src="music/falador_party_room.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio> thank you!

Comment: also note that the audio tag is not inside the area tag.

Comment: @shayk so you have a map (`<area>`) and only one `audio` tag? So when you click on a point then the `audio` tag will be updated?

Comment: i have a lot of area and audio tags there.  i put here only one of each for the example. i do want it to be responsive or something that will not force the browser to run all 300 of my audio tags at once

Comment: @shayk I beg your pardon, but is a little too diffucult wothout the full code, sorry...if you have got some problems to adapt the code just post another question or update this one with a chunk of generated code

Comment: i think i have another solution that might work. i only need to know - how can i delete a children of a node? like if i got <iframe> as a child of a <div>, how can i delete this <iframe> with js?

Comment: @shayk I have found this source: [link](http://red-team-design.com/removing-an-element-with-plain-javascript-remove-method/)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem happens because browser tries to preload the audio for each audio tag.
So the answer is to set the attribute preload in the audio tag to value none

```
<audio preload="none">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<audio src="abc.mp3"controls class="audioDemo" preload="none"></audio> 
<audio src="abc1.mp3"controls class="audioDemo" preload="none"></audio> 
<audio src="abc2.mp3"controls class="audioDemo" preload="none"></audio> 
<audio src="abc3.mp3"controls class="audioDemo" preload="none"></audio> 
<audio src="abc4.mp3"controls class="audioDemo" preload="none"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes don't leave the src attribute empty, but give to src a valid blank and short file.mp3.
Then when user click or whatever replace the src by the good file, like this:

document.getElementById("audio8").src = "song.mp3";

Also, depending of how is made your page, if audio's appear block after block, have a look to lazysize.js for smoothly load your content when scroolling. Easy to use and powerful. 
https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes

Answer (score 0):

Your browser tries to preload the audio for each audio tag. So the answer is to set the attribute preload in the audio tag to value none
use can use: `<audio controls preload="none">`

Comment: Sunil, your comment starts well, but the end could use some revision - I think there's been a mistake with formatting.

Comment: Danyal Aytekin, thanks for advice & complete code is -Ex : 
<audio controls preload="none">
 <source  src="song.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

Comment: thanks, - DanyalAytekin